# Merge SQL results by creating new field?

Tags: sql, pivot

I'd like to take two records like this:

```
Id   Fname  Lname  Email
------------------------------------
1    John   Doe    jdoe@example.com
2    John   Doe    doej1@place.net
```

And combine them in such a way that I have only one record:

```
Id   Fname  Lname Email1            Email2
---------------------------------------------------
1    John   Doe   jdoe@example.com  doej@place.net
```

As you can see, this would add a field to my record that otherwise does not exist in the database. Is this possible or do I have to find another way?

NOTE: I am not able to change the database structure in any way.

Comment: Which Database are you using and what's the version?

Comment: Do you need to have TWO email fields, or is one delimited field ok?

Comment: Do you know that there will only ever be two email addresses you need to do this with, or could it sometimes be 3 or 4 or more...?

Comment: There are actually many possible (on the order of 20 or so I believe). I used email to show a simpler example.

Delimited will most likely work fine, but I'm not yet positive of that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The database product and version makes all the difference here. Assuming that you are using something that supports ranking functions (e.g. SQL Server 2005+)

```
Select FName, LName
    , Min( Case When Rnk = 1 Then Z.Email End ) As Email1
    , Min( Case When Rnk = 2 Then Z.Email End ) As Email2
From    (
        Select FName, LName, Email
            , Row_Number() Over ( Partition By FName, LName Order By Id ) As Rnk
        From MyTable
        ) As Z
Group By Z.FName, Z.LName
```

If you are not using a product that supports ranking functions (e.g. MySQL), then it is trickier. One solution that should work on almost all database systems would be:

```
Select FName, LName
    , Min( Case When Rnk = 1 Then Z.Email End ) As Email1
    , Min( Case When Rnk = 2 Then Z.Email End ) As Email2
From    (
        Select FName, LName, Email
            , (Select Count(*)
                From MyTable As T2
                Where T1.FName = T2.FName
                    And T2.LName = T2.LName
                    And T2.Id < T1.Id) + 1 As Rnk
        From MyTable As T1
        ) As Z
Group By Z.FName, Z.LName
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using SQL Server, see this article: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/175574

It's got an example with different data, but the task is the same.  You can usually find examples for other RDBMS's by searching for  "Rotate Table  [rdbmstype]" on Google or Bing

Answer (score 0):

```
    select x.Id as ID, x.Fname as Fname, x.Lname as Lname, x.Email as Email1, y.Email as email2 from
        (select id, fname, lname, email from table) as x inner join
        (select id, email from table) as y on x.id = y.id and x.email != y.email
```

Probably a little inefficient, but it'll get the job done.

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL you can use [`GROUP_CONCAT()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat):

```
SELECT Fname, Lname, GROUP_CONCAT(email) emails
FROM tbl
GROUP BY Fname, Lname;
```

If you need emails in separate fields, you can split resulting `emails` string in your programming environment (like `explode(',', $result['emails'])` in PHP), or use self-join (works only for 2 email fields):

```
SELECT a.Fname, a.Lname, a.Email Email1, b.email Email2
FROM tbl a JOIN tbl b ON a.Fname = b.Fname AND a.Lname = b.Lname AND a.Email != b.Email
```

adding contraption:

```
GROUP BY CONCAT(GREATEST(Email1,Email2),LEAST(Email1,Email2))
```

to get rid of duplicate email pairs.